# How to refer to the count value of number of lines in a lstlisting

Tags: listings, counters

I need to refer to to the count value of the number of lines in a listing. Is there a way to do that ?

```
    \lstinputlisting[caption={SPARQL query used...},label={lst:sqry}]{codes/sparql_query.sparql}
```

I can refer to this listing in a document by using \ref{lst:sqry}, but I need to be able to automatically count the number of lines in that listing and refer to the value.

I would deeply appreciate any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Does this only hold for `\lstinputlisting`s or for regular `lstlisting`s as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should do the trick using counter `lst@lineno`. The example creates a reference after the listings that contains the number of lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lstcountlabel}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \edef\@currentlabel{\the\numexpr\the\lst@lineno-1}%
    \label{#1}%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
  columns=flexible,
  numbers=left,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  caption={The listings has \ref{lst:job} lines.},
]
{\jobname.tex}
\lstcountlabel{lst:job}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Brilliant ! Thank you very much for the prompt reply. Will surely mention this help in my acknowledgement :)

Answer (score 5):

This solution uses a different approach and was written as answer for question ["Listings: total line number count"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115957/16967) that was closed too fast.

This solution uses a different approach than [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109216/16967):

- Also a label is used to remember the number of code lines. This variant uses package `zref` for this purpose.
- The number of code lines is made available by macro `\mylstlines` in the caption for the listing. That saves the user from the need to invent unique label names. Counter `mylstlisting` identifies a listing and the value is used in the name of the label.
- The code lines are counted via counter `mylstlines` by hooking into the listings hook `EveryPar`. This way, the value of `mylstlines` should not be affected by options that affect the selected line range (`firstline`) or that change the printed line numbers (`firstnumber`).

Example file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{zref-base}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{mylstlisting}
\newcounter{mylstlines}
\lst@AddToHook{PreSet}{%
  \stepcounter{mylstlisting}%
  \setcounter{mylstlines}{0}%
}
\lst@AddToHook{EveryPar}{%
  \stepcounter{mylstlines}%
}
\lst@AddToHook{ExitVars}{%
  \begingroup
    \zref@wrapper@immediate{%
      \zref@setcurrent{default}{\the\value{mylstlines}}%
      \zref@labelbyprops{mylstlines\the\value{mylstlisting}}{default}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

% \mylstlines print number of lines inside listing caption
\newcommand*{\mylstlines}{%
  \protect\zref@extract{mylstlines\the\value{mylstlisting}}{default}%
}
\makeatother

% cosmetics
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible,
    numbers=left, stepnumber=1}

\begin{document}
  \lstlistoflistings
  \lstinputlisting[%
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    caption={Example with \mylstlines\ lines.},
  ]{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW [off topic]: The number of code lines in this example is the answer to another question.