# Listings: total line number count

Tags: listings, counters

Is there a way to determine how many lines a listings-environment has (included via `\lstinputlisting`) and display it in a text or caption? I found the counter `\thelstnumber`. But if it is used before a listings environment the counter is 1 and afterwards it is equal to `linecount+1`.
The best solution in my eyes would be, if the counter would be accessible via the listings label.

Comment: You have to define a new label.

Comment: I'm afraid I can not quite follow you. I assume you mean a label for the listing. And then do what with it?

Comment: At the end of the environment `lstlisting` you have to write the line number to the aux file. So you can refer to the line-number.

Comment: This is the solution you are looking for: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109195/how-to-refer-to-the-count-value-of-number-of-lines-in-a-lstlisting?rq=1. Thanks for the hint with the label. Didn't search stack well enough, topic already existed.